# Loop through specific array of object and assign to new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have this below userData coming from backend. `userData` can be null or `userData.accountDetails` can be null. I need to loop through `userData.accountDetails` specificially. And assign the entire object `userData` to a new object `newUserData`.

```
const userData = {
  age:45,
  sex: 'Male',
  accountDetails: [
    {
      accountId: '4567',
      accountName: 'checkings',
      balance: 3000,
    },
    {
      accountId: '1234',
      accountName: 'savings',
      balance: 3000,
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve this, i perform the following steps

```
const newUserData = null;
if(userData !== null && userData !== undefined) {
  newUserData.age = userData.age,
  newUserData.sex = userData.sex,
  
  if(userData.accountDetails !== null && userData.accountDetails !== undefined) {
    newUserData.accountDetails = userData.accountDetails.map(el => {
      return {
        accountId: el.accountId,
        accountName:el.accountName,
        balance: el.balance + 10;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note, i am doing `el.balance + 10` beacause i want the new object to have balance of 10 added to original balance. Actually i have a more complex calculation to do, but i simplified it for this example.

The current code doesnot work and it doesnot enter the loop and exits without giving a error  message in console.  how can i achieve this reassigning of object and loop through array of accountDetails to get new object as per desired above.

Comment: Missing quote after `male` in the data.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette- sorry tat was a typo when i entered the code here. corrected it

Comment: There is a couple typos... But the main issue is to declare `newUserData` as `null` instead of an empty object. See you code working in this  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/xxOgMGe?editors=0012)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette- indeed. tat was the mistake. i thought if i assign it as null. i can decide the structure of the object later on. but the creation part should be mentioned as an object. thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

You could map it just like you did with the age and sex. Also, you can check for the object being null by doing a `if (userData)`

```
const newUserData = null;
if(userData) {
  newUserData.age = userData.age,
  newUserData.sex = userData.sex,
  
  if(userData.accountDetails) {
    newUserData.accountDetails.Id = el.accountId
    newUserData.accountDetails.accountName = el.accountName
    newUserData.accountDetails.balance = el.balance + 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```